# Как задать несколько значений переменной Java, и добавить ее в список?

Tags: java, list, переменные, arraylist

Я делаю консольную java игру, карта с видом сверху, и на ней есть стены. У каждой стены есть координаты Х и У. Мне нужен список в котором будут храниться координаты этих стен. А потом нужно сравнить координаты стен с координатами игрока. У меня есть нужный мне код на python, но нужно переписать его на Java.

```
x = 1
y = 5

for i in range(5):
    s = (24,34) // координата стены(рандом сам добавлю)
    ss.append(s) // все стены
// теперь проверка
if (x,y) in ss:
    // координаты игрока и стены совпадают
```

Помогите, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Модно записывать в строку, и парить через запятую. Можно просто массив из двух значений использовать, да до фига вариантов впринцепе, в чем проблема не понятно

Comment: Я новичок в java, поэтому для меня это проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    static class Coord {
        int x;
        int y;

        public Coord(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("(x:%s, y:%s)", this.x, this.y);
        }

        public boolean eq(int x, int y) {
            return this.x == x & this.y == y;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Coord> ss = new ArrayList<>();
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ss.add(new Coord(rand.nextInt(100), rand.nextInt(100)));
        }
        System.out.println("Координаты стен: " + ss);

        int x = ss.get(3).x;
        int y = ss.get(3).y;

        // теперь проверка
        System.out.printf("Ищем координаты: x=%s, y=%s%n", x, y);
        boolean coord_eq = false;
        for (Coord c : ss) {
            if (c.eq(x, y)) {// координаты игрока и стены совпадают?
                coord_eq = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Координаты%sсовпали%n", coord_eq ? " " : " НЕ ");
    }
}
```

```
Координаты стен: [(x:53, y:79), (x:27, y:78), (x:73, y:5), (x:64, y:61), (x:85, y:61)]
Ищем координаты: x=64, y=61
Координаты совпали
```

Comment: Я новичок в джава, можете пожалуйста объяснить мне некоторые вещи? 1) Зачем после импорта всего пакета java.util импортировать Random из этого же пакета? 2) что такое static class, и разве можно ставить один класс внутри другого? 3) что такое coord?

Comment: 1. Рудимент, убрал
2. https://javarush.com/groups/posts/modifikator-static-java; можно.
3. Это класс с координатами x,y